# Apostrophe and the next symbol turned into a Japanese symbol in a text file

Tags: windows, character-encoding

I have Windows XP with three languages used: Russian (as the system language), English, and Japanese (support for Asian languages is installed).

I have a subtitle file where everything looks [normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5JC0.png) in Notepad++, however in normal Notepad and in Zoom Player (which I'm using to watch the video) there is a problem: when there is an apostrophe followed by a letter, they [turn into a Japanese symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqbZo.png). *'t* becomes 稚, *'r* becomes 池, *'l* becomes 値, etc.

What can I do to fix this subtitle file so that it looks normal in my video player?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the help of the user oals... First I select Windows-1251 encoding in Notepad++, then I click on "convert to UTF-8 with BOM" and it looks correct now. It is important to select that encoding first, otherwise it won't work.